# Openssh key to access remote sftp server from RHEL

Tags: ssh, sftp, ssh-keys, rhel6

I have generate public key and private key in windows 7 through puttygen then change the key to openssh in puttygen through export key. Now I want to use this openssh key to access my sftp server from RHEL 6. what kind of steps I need to take in RHEL so can use openssh key and access the sftp server. I am new thats why thanks for cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

With the user that you want to access the sftp server automatically, you need to first do an

```
ssh-keygen
```

This generates an ssh keypair. Press enter for all questions to accept the defaults.

```
ssh-copy-id YOUR_SFTP_SERVER_ADDRESS
```

This will make your sftp server trust your ssh key

Following this all ssh access to the sftp server will not prompt you to enter a password. Likewise, all scp's will not ask for a password. So you can fetch your files like so:

```
scp YOUR_SFTP_SERVER_ADDRESS:PATH_TO_FILES_ON_SFTP_SERVER   DESTINATION_DIRECTORY
```

example

```
scp 192.168.0.53:/home/john/shared_files/  /tmp/
```

This will bring John's files to the local directory /tmp

Hope this helps!